# how can i use relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

My schema is as follows:

```
channel table:
id int unsigned primary key auto increment,
name varchar(30) not null,
...

category table:
id int unsigned primary key auto increment,
channel_id int unsigned index,
name varchar(30) not null,
...

article table:
id int unsigned primary key auto increment,
category_id int unsigned index,
title varchar(90) not null,
content text not null,
...
```

so, every article belong to a specific category and the category belongs to a specific channel.

my question is:

how can i search all the articles with the category name and channel name (the relationship is ready in my code)?

i have tried

```
$articles = App\Article::latest()->with('category')->with('channel')->get();
```

but it does not work, anyone who can help me? thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search through the related tables you should use joins like this:

```
$articles = App\Article::latest()
    ->select('article.*')
    ->join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'category_id')
    ->join('channel', 'channel.id', '=', 'channel_id')
    ->where('category.name', 'LIKE', "%{$name}%")
    ->orWhere('channel.name', 'LIKE', "%{$name}%")
    ->groupBy('article.id')
    ->get();
```